# put div at bottom of page or viewport which is larger

Tags: jquery, html, css

i need to put a div with background at the bottom of the page no metter if the content of the page is long enough to push it to the bottom or not

at the moment i use this code

```
#bottomBar {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}​
```

the problem with this is that if the content of the page larger then what is available in the view port that img is stuck floating in the middle of nothing

[example of when this script dosn't work](http://jsfiddle.net/s7tPL/)
[example of when this script works well](http://jsfiddle.net/4xUdN/1/)

Comment: You can try this: [keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page)

Comment: great job jfrej
you are the only one who understood the problem
post it as an answer so i can select it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#bottomBar {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}​
```

Answer (score -1):

If your image is failed to load you cannot see the div.

Specify width and height and also background to see the div

```
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
bottom: 0px;
position: absolute;
```

[See the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/hW2bB/)

it works fine